# python lxml objectify скопировать элемент со всеми субэлементами

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Есть файл формата XML, в нем, в корне есть много дочерних элементов, которые имеют атрибуты и свои дочерние элементы. Необходимо скопировать один корневой дочерний элемент и добавить эту копию с измененными атрибутами.

Из

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config FS_Version="3.1.3.0" CurrentDateTime="10.09.2020 20:38:36" DateTimeISO="2020-09-10T20:38:36.789+05:00">
  <drv idx="0" name="Компьютер"/>
  <drv idx="1" name="Удаленный сервер"/>
  <zone idx="0" no="101" GUID="{858BD75D4FA}" name="zone1" idZones="0">
    <param name="ZoneType" type="Int" value="1"/>
    <param name="Category" type="Byte" value="0"/>
  </zone>
  <zone idx="1" no="102" GUID="{4B7FFE8665A}" name="zone2" idZones="0">
    <param name="ZoneType" type="Int" value="1"/>
    <param name="Category" type="Byte" value="0"/>
  </zone>
</config>
```

Получить:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config FS_Version="3.1.3.0" CurrentDateTime="10.09.2020 20:38:36" DateTimeISO="2020-09-10T20:38:36.789+05:00">
  <drv idx="0" name="Компьютер"/>
  <drv idx="1" name="Удаленный сервер"/>
  <zone idx="0" no="101" GUID="{858BD75D4FA}" name="zone1" idZones="0">
    <param name="ZoneType" type="Int" value="1"/>
    <param name="Category" type="Byte" value="0"/>
  </zone>
  <zone idx="1" no="102" GUID="{4B7FFE8665A}" name="zone2" idZones="0">
    <param name="ZoneType" type="Int" value="1"/>
    <param name="Category" type="Byte" value="0"/>
  </zone>
  <zone idx="2" no="103" GUID="{}" name="newZone" idZones="0">
    <param name="ZoneType" type="Int" value="1"/>
    <param name="Category" type="Byte" value="0"/>
  </zone>
</config>
```

То есть один-в-один скопировать элемент с тегом zone, изменив только атрибуты.

Понимаю, что можно составить элемент заново, но полагаю есть метод позволяющий просто его скопировать.
Хотелось бы что-то типа

```
from lxml import etree as et, objectify as objtf

with open('file.xml', encoding='utf-8') as fobj:
    xml = fobj.read()

root = objtf.fromstring(xml)

newZ = root.zone[0]
newZ.set('name', 'newZone')
newZ.set('GUID', '')
newZ.set('no', '103')
newZ.set('idx', '2')

root.zone = newZ
```

Таким макаром запись добавляется, но вместе с тем меняется и исходная.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ на англоязычном stackoverflow - [etree Clone Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005975/etree-clone-node)

Замечательно работает [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4006135) вариант с `copy.deepcopy()` от пользователя Steven.

Следующий код решил поставленную задачу:

```
newZ = copy.deepcopy(root.zone[0])
newZ.set('name', 'newZone')
newZ.set('GUID', '')
newZ.set('no', '103')
newZ.set('idx', '2')

root.append(newZ)
```